# C# - How to redirect with HttpRequestMessage

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have problem to redirect to other page, for example, while i am keeping Credential Cache. I'm using:

```
cCache.Add(new Uri("http://mypage.com"), "Basic", new NetworkCredential("admin", "admin"));
```

and with:

```
 using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = cCache }))
        {
            var request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage()
            {
                RequestUri = new Uri("http://mypage.com"),
                Method = HttpMethod.Get,
            };

            var result = new HttpResponseMessage();
            var requestTask = client.SendAsync(request).ContinueWith((argRequestTask) =>
            {
                result = argRequestTask.Result; 
            });
            requestTask.Wait();
        }
```

status code that i get is 200 OK, and that is good. Result that i get is content of that page and that is good to, but im still on same page. If i redirect with:

```
Response.Redirect("http://mypage.com");
```

i lose my credentials. How i can solve this? tnx

Comment: It is unclear on whether you are initiating the redirect from the client or server side.